# Editar dentro de um modal

Tags: jquery, html, css

Eu tenho uma tabela com dados e um dos campos tem 1 botão de editar. O que eu quero é que, ao clicar, ele me abra um modal com os dados todos preenchidos da linha respetiva que eu cliquei. Eu já consegui fazer isso, mas não era com um modal, era com um ficheiro à parte, e agora queria num modal. Será que me podiam ajudar?

[image: Imagem1]

[image: imagem 2]

Código do modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="large-Modal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title text-center text-primary"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Alterar Cliente</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
         </div>
         <form id="edit_equipa" method="POST" action="clientes.php?edit=1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="modal-body">
               <input type="hidden" name="action" value="executeEdit">
               <input type="hidden" class="" name="alterar_cliente_id" id="alterar_cliente_id" value="<?php echo $row['cliente_id']; ?>">

               <div class="form-group form-float col-lg-12">
                  <label><strong>ID Cliente</strong></label>
                  <div class="form-line">
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled required ><?php echo $row['cliente_id']; ?></input>
                  </div>
               </div>

               <div class="form-group form-float col-lg-12">
                  <label><strong>Nome</strong></label>
                  <div class="form-line">
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="alterar_nome" id="alterar_nome" value="<?php echo $row['nome'];?>" required >
                  </div>
               </div>
            </td>

               <div class="form-group form-float col-lg-12">
                  <label><strong>Morada</strong></label>
                  <div class="form-line">
                     <textarea class="form-control" name="alterar_morada" id="alterar_morada" required ><?php echo $row['morada'];?></textarea>
                     <!--<label class="form-label">Data</label>-->
                  </div>
               </div>

               <div class="form-group form-float col-lg-12">
                  <label><strong>Telefone</strong></label>
                  <div class="form-line">
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="alterar_telefone" id="alterar_telefone" value="<?php echo $row['telefone'];?>" required >
                     <!--<label class="form-label">Data</label>-->
                  </div>
               </div>
            </td>

               <div class="form-group form-float col-lg-12">
                  <label><strong>Email</strong></label>
                  <div class="form-line">
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="alterar_email" id="alterar_email" value="<?php echo $row['email'];?>" required >
                     <!--<label class="form-label">Data</label>-->
                  </div>
               </div>

               <div class="form-group form-float col-lg-12">
                  <label><strong>Contribuinte</strong></label>
                  <div class="form-line">
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="alterar_contribuinte" id="alterar_contribuinte" value="<?php echo $row['contribuinte'];?>" required >
                     <!--<label class="form-label">Data</label>-->
                  </div>
               </div>

               <div class="form-group form-float col-lg-12">
                  <label><strong>Horas</strong></label>
                  <div class="form-line">
                     <input type="time" class="form-control" name="alterar_horas" id="alterar_horas" value="<?php echo $row['horas'];?>" required >
                     <!--<label class="form-label">Data</label>-->
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default waves-effect " data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" id="btn_inserir">Alterar</button>
            </div>
         </form>
```

Código do botão da tabela

```
<td style="vertical-align: middle;">
   <div>
      <a id="btn_editar?<?php echo $row['cliente_id']; ?>" href="#div_editar" class="btn btn-info btn-xs waves-effect" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#large-Modal1">
         <i class="fa fa-lg fa-edit"></i><!--edit-->
      </a>
      <a href="#" onclick="if (confirm('Tem a certeza que deseja eliminar este Cliente?')) window.location='iframes/clientes_apagar.php?cliente_id=<?php echo $row['cliente_id']; ?>';return false" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs waves-effect">
         <i class="fa fa-lg fa-trash"></i><!--delete-->
      </a>
   </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se os dados que o usuário vai editar já estão sendo exibidos na tabela pode utilizar este exemplo de código abaixo:

```js
$('body').on("click", ".edit", function() {
    
    $('#nomeEditar').val($(this).parents('tr').find('td').eq(1).text());
    $('#emailEditar').val($(this).parents('tr').find('td').eq(2).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Ações</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Carlos</td>
      <td>carlos@mail.com</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditar"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Cesar</td>
      <td>cesar@mail.com</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditar"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Luis</td>
      <td>luis@mail.com</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditar"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalEditar">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Editar Registro</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="text" id="nomeEditar">
        <input type="text" id="emailEditar">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="confEditar">Editar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> A vantagem aqui é não fazer uma nova requisição a cada nova possível edição.
>   Caso os dados não estejam todos visíveis, não terá opção a não ser requisitar os dados por ajax.

Comment: Penso que essa seja a melhor opção!!

Comment: É isso mesmo Obrigado pela ajuda!!

Answer (score 1):

A melhor forma de trazer os dados dos registro dentro do *modal* de edição é utilizar o *AJAX*.

No objeto `#btn_editar`, você terá que definir o atributo `onclick` dessa maneira:

`<a href="#" onclick="editar('<?php echo $row['cliente_id']; ?>');">...</a>`

No seu *JS*, deve declarar a função que fará a requisição via *AJAX* e que colocará os dados dentro do *modal*:

```
function editar(id)
{
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://host_da_aplicacao/ajax.php?id=' + id,
    type: 'get',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (dados) {
      if (dados.status) {
        // Reseta o form para evitar conflitos, preenche os campos e chama o modal
        $('#edit_equipa')[0].reset();
        $('#alterar_cliente_id').val(id);
        $('#alterar_nome').val(dados.nome);
        $('#alterar_morada').val(dados.morada);
        $('#alterar_telefone').val(dados.telefone);
        $('#alterar_email').val(dados.email);
        $('#alterar_contribuinte').val(dados.contribuinte);
        $('#alterar_horas').val(dados.horas);
        $('#large-Modal1').modal('show');
      }
    }
  });
}
```

E no arquivo `ajax.php`, você deve realizar a busca na sua tabela com o `$_GET['id']` recebido e então criar um `array` dinâmico com os dados que será convertido em *JSON*:

```
<?php
  // Consulta a tabela antes disso e traz os dados na variável $resultado

  $dados = [
    'status'       => TRUE, // Defina TRUE se a consulta retornar com sucesso, senão defina FALSE
    'nome'         => $resultado['nome'],
    'morada'       => $resultado['morada'],
    'telefone'     => $resultado['telefone'],
    'email'        => $resultado['email'],
    'contribuinte' => $resultado['contribuinte'],
    'horas'        => $resultado['horas']
  ];

  echo json_encode($dados);
```

Comment: Também é uma boa alternativa e poderá dar jeito futuramente obrigado pelo tempo e pela ajuda!!

Comment: Opa! Precisando estamos aí! :D

Comment: Muito Obrigado, não há melhor escolha que o StackOverflow ahah !!